# How to add a list of different objects to a constructor?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I have a problem, namely I have an AdapterRecycler, and in my constructor I have a List <>item, but in that I have classes Cake, Dinner, Drinks, Salads and all these objects I have to throw into the list because I must use my AdapterRecycler designer in few places in the code, but how to do?

For example:

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>{

private List<Cake> cakeList = Collections.emptyList();
private List<Dinner> dinnerList = Collections.emptyList();
private List<Drinks> drinksList = Collections.emptyList();
private List<Salads> saladsList = Collections.emptyList();

***//So how to put other lists in one constructor?***
//
*In the code below I still use methods to retrieve Names and Resources, so how do I tell the program to know which list to return? I can't duplicate a constructor with the same parameters, so is there any solution to this problem?*

 public RecyclerAdapter(Activity activity, List<Cake> items) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.cakeList = items;
    }

*//I can't do this. So how?*

public RecyclerAdapter(Activity activity, List<Salads> items) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.saladsList = items;
    }

}
```

***RecyclerAdapter.class***

```
class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {




private Activity activity;
List<Salatki> items = Collections.emptyList();

public RecyclerAdapter(Activity activity, List<Salatki> items) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.items = items;
}

private Listener listener;


public static interface Listener {
    public void onClick(int position);
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private CardView cardView;
    public ViewHolder(CardView v) {
        super(v);
        cardView=v;
    }
}


public void setListener(Listener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
public CaptionedImagesAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
   CardView cv = (CardView) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.card_captioned_image, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(cv);

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        CardView cardView = holder.cardView;
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)cardView.findViewById(R.id.info_image);

        Drawable drawable = cardView.getResources().getDrawable(items.get(position).getImageResourceId());
        imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
        imageView.setContentDescription(items.get(position).getName());

        TextView textView = (TextView)cardView.findViewById(R.id.info_text);
        textView.setText(items.get(position).getName());


    cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(listener != null) {
                listener.onClick(position);
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create base class having methods "getName()" and "getResourceId()", then use it in Adapter.

```
class Food {
    private String name;
    private int resourceId;
    // getters/setters
}

class Cake extends Food {

}

class Dinner extends Food {

}
```

Then use field of type `List<Food>` in your Adapter.

UPD. Adapter constructor:

```
public <T extends Food> RecyclerAdapter(Activity activity, List<T> items) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.items = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Food item : items) {
        this.items.add(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it is still not working.              
When I try to use the adapter it gets the answer that java.util.List <Foods> can not be applied to java.util.List <Cake> etc ...

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your adapter class has to take a List of items as an argument in it's constructor. Something like this:

```
public class Item {
  final String name;
  final int resId;
  public Item(String name, int resId){
   this.name=name;
   this.resId=resId;
   }
}
```

and you constructor like this:

```
public RecyclerAdapter(Activity activity, List<Item> items) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.items = items;
}
```

Then before you create your adapter try to **Map** your food lists and add all of them to one single list like this:

```
List<Item> items=new ArrayList();
for(Cake c: cakes){
  items.add(new Item(c.name,c.resId));
}
//same for the rest food lists
```

Also if you would like to know inside your Adapter the kind of food that it's item belongs to, add one more property e.g `type`(could be enum) to item's class

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This solution is great.